# How to Put a text on the end of print(count ) (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am trying to put "Start" on the end of my count. here is the code i have typed:

```
for count in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(count, end=" ")
```

Output i am getting: `5 4 3 2 1`
What i want : `5 4 3 2 1 START`

Comment: just put a print('Start') just after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way:

```
for count in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(count, end=" ")
print("START")
```

else:

```
for count in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(count, end=" ")
    if count == 1:
        print("START")
```

Comment: @AnmolSinghVirk sure. welcome to SO. Next time, try doing what you want to achive and add that code alongwith the error you get :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for count in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(count, end=" ")
print(“Start”)
```

Comment: This is a copy of my answer. Please dont code codes on SO. Either delete or change it :)

Comment: @Joshua Well, you probably posted yours at the same time I did. Btw, that’s not “your” answer. That’s just the most obvious way to do it. And honestly I don’t need to copy anybody’s answer to feed my ego :)

Comment: well it is here, because duplicaes answers are not allowed in SO

Comment: So feel free to remove yours then. Mine is staying.